# Jquery - How can I increment an id in different parent div?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, increment

In my project, I need to register ids so that when I click on a button that has a checkbox type, it only checks the button where I clicked.

In the custom-switch class, I wanted to put an id in the input and a for in the label. I managed to display the id and the for but all the input and label of each click-and-get-containerDiv class have the same id as the others.

My html code :

```html
<div class="col-2 click-and-get-container click-and-get-containerDiv">
    <div class="checkbox-container">
        <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="1">
            <label class="custom-control-label">Activate click &amp; get</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 d-none click-and-get-amount-form" id="click-and-get-amount-form_all">
        <input type="number" class="form-control click-and-get-amount" value step="0.01" placeholder="Price (EUR)">
        <span class="small text-danger click-and-get-amount-error d-none"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

For the js code, I used a for so that my incrimentation stops at the total number of gg class there are in the html page (I checked with a console.log()).

My javascript code :

```js
for (let idClickAndGet = 1; idClickAndGet <= $('.click-and-get-containerDiv').length;) {
    $(`.custom-control-input:nth-child(${idClickAndGet})`).attr('id', `click-and-get${idClickAndGet}`);
    $(`.custom-control-label:nth-child(${idClickAndGet})`).attr('for', `click-and-get${idClickAndGet}`);
    idClickAndGet++;
}
```

Comment: Your problem is in the use of `:nth-child` - it's not what you want here as it relates to the immediate parents of each input/label, but you want all inputs/labels   Change to loop from 0 and use `$(`.custom-control-input`).eq(idClickAndGet)` https://jsfiddle.net/50cqus3a/

Comment: Thanks, It works! I don't know the el() function. I will learn about the el() function.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/eq/